# Allow users to edit just the vocabulary that belong to them?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I allow users to create a taxonomy vocabulary. Then I need to be able to give permission to each user to edit their own vocabulary. I looked at the permission page but I don´t see anything like **Edit own vocabularies**.

Is there any way I can accomplish this.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you use Drupal 7 or D6 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Taxonomy Delegate module (http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_delegate) and the Vocabulary Permissions (http://drupal.org/project/vocabperms) let you delegate administration of a taxonomy to a role, but they do not do it for an individual user. You might be able to write a custom module from here, but what you're proposing goes a little against the role-based permission architecture. My search didn't seem to find one that does exactly what you want.

Comment: thanks, but as you said I should take a different approach to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd lean toward having users create nodes and using node references or relates in place of term references.  Then use a view on the node reference that limited the choices to those items the user had created.  I'm not a big fan of terms tho, so I'll admit my solution is a little biased.

Comment: Thanks Brent, I´m not a fan of taxonomies neither, but I need to make a menu with the terms created for the user and I also need the nesting capability. Taxonomy allows me to do this. This is why I thought of taxonomy to do it. I can do it by creating nodes, but even though I can create a menu with them I don´t know how to nest nodes.

Answer (score 0):

The nesting can be achieved with draggable views https://www.drupal.org/project/draggableviews